# How do I unquote in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

There is a "quote" formatting option within Gmail, but no "unquote" to undo the deeper quote level. How do I unquote text?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By clicking on the decrease indent icon.

1. Mark the text which you want to unindent, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all
2. Click on the "Indent less" button, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

[image]

3. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work very well for me. I had a series of numbered lists with a line of text, line break (shift+enter), image, and another line break (shift+enter, for visual separation) under each number/bullet.  When I clicked the decrease indent icon it wiped out all the text in the numbered lists so I just had multiple series of images without any explanatory text above each one.

Comment: This doesn't work if the content being unquoted includes a list, indented block, sub-quote, etc.

Comment: Great answer! Thx, @Frank Dernoncourt!

Answer (score 5):

Click on the A-underscore icon for the formatting buttons. The [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8260?hl=en) page lists the following:

###### Quote:

PC: <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

###### Indent Less: (ALSO UNQUOTES!)

PC: <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

###### Indent More:

PC: <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

The shortcut keys also show when you hover over the icons.

Comment: Thx for your answer, @Dagelf!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome you can use the [UnQuote for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unquote-for-gmail/johachenlhehijdicggbfbkdkkeikilf) extension.

Comment: That extension is for removing the rest of the thread when replying to an email, not what was asked